# Combinatorics problem: # of arithmetic problems possible

Tags: combinatorics

"How many arithmetic problems of the following form are possible? You must use each of the digits 1 through 9, they must appear in numerical order from left to right, and you can use any combination of the + and * symbols you like, as long as the resulting expression makes mathematical sense. For example, 1234+5678+9 and 123456+789 and 123456789 are three possibilities, but 1**23456789 is not."

We know the numbers are ordered as: 1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9 where the _'s can be filled by one of the three operations '+', '*', and ''.

There are 2*3{n-1} ways to arrange these operations. I just don't know how to use the information correctly for the problem. Where 'n' is 8 I believe.

Advice/Hints?

edit: 2*3^{n-1} is totally wrong. Brain was stuck on previous problem. Sorry.

Comment: Where would you get the "$2\times$" term from?

Comment: You are very close, but this isn't a question about arranging, just making many choices. Three choices for the first blank then three choices for the second blank, etc.

Comment: Peter, I think 2*3^{n-1} is a mistake now. Sorry. John, would the answer be 3^8?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: Thank you! This was actually a very simple problem. I don't know why I keep making these problems difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each '_' may be either empty, $*$, or $+$ -- so a total of three possibilities. We have 8 such '_'. So by the fundamental principle of counting we are left with a total of $3^8$ possibilities.